# How to successfully implement 'heatmap plot and save' loop in R with ggplot2

Tags: r, for-loop, plot, ggplot2, heatmap

I'm working with survey data. There are two groups of survey items, and each group has three items. There are two respondents in my survey sample.

I am attempting to generate heat maps by survey item groups, where:

- the respondents are on the 'y' axis
- survey items they responded to are on the 'x' axis.

Here is a fully reproducible example:

```
    wd <- "D:/Desktop/"
    setwd(wd)

    #--create dataframe

    respondent = c("Respondent_1", "Respondent_1", "Respondent_1","Respondent_1", "Respondent_1", "Respondent_1",
                   "Respondent_2", "Respondent_2", "Respondent_2","Respondent_2", "Respondent_2", "Respondent_2")
    item = c("Item_1", "Item_2", "Item_3","Item_1", "Item_2", "Item_3",
             "Item_1", "Item_2", "Item_3","Item_1", "Item_2", "Item_3") 

    item_group = c("Group_1","Group_1","Group_1","Group_2","Group_2","Group_2",
                   "Group_1","Group_1","Group_1","Group_2","Group_2","Group_2")
    score = c(1, 40, 100, 100, 30, 12, 
              2, 15, 80, 77, 44, 10) 

    high_value_color = c("darkred", "darkred", "darkred",
                         "brown3", "brown3", "brown3")

    plot_df = data.frame(respondent, item, item_group, score, high_value_color) 

    #--write function
    #--inspired from this: http://www.reed.edu/data-at-reed/resources/R/loops_with_ggplot2.html

    plot_list <- unique(plot_df$item_group)

    survey_items.graph <- function(df, na.rm = TRUE, ...) {

    #--loop to generate heatmaps for each group

      for (i in seq_along(plot_list)) { 

        plot <-  ggplot(aes(x = df$item[df$item_group == plot_list[i]], 
                            y = df$respondent[df$item_group==plot_list[i]]), 
                        data = subset(df, df$item_group == plot_list[i])) +
          geom_tile(aes(fill = df$score[df$item_group == plot_list[i]]), colour = "black") + 
          scale_fill_gradient2(low = "azure1", 
                               high = df$high_value_color[df$item_group == plot_list[i]], 
                               guide = "colorbar") +
          geom_text(aes(label = df$score[df$item_group==plot_list[i]], 
                        hjust = 0.5, 
                        angle = 90), 
                        size = 4) +
          ggtitle(df$item_group[df$item_group==plot_list[i]]) +
          theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
                panel.background = element_blank(),
                plot.title = element_text(size = 7, face="bold"),
                axis.text.y = element_text(size = 7, face ="bold"),
                axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1),
                axis.title = element_blank(),
                legend.position = "none")
        # save plots as .png
        ggsave(plot, file=paste(wd,"plots/heatmap for ", plot_list[i], ".png", sep=""), scale=2)
        print(plot)
      }
    }

    #--load ggplot2

    library(ggplot2)

    #--execute function on plot dataframe
    survey_items.graph(plot_df)
```

When I execute my code, I got the following two plots:

[image: current plots]

My intuition tells me that I'm not doing something right with the 'high' argument of the 'scale_fill_gradient2' portion of my code.

As a test, when I've replaced the value for the 'high' argument with just an acceptable color string value (e.g. 'brown3', other colors can be found [here](http://research.stowers-institute.org/efg/R/Color/Chart/)), I get the plots to behave as I want them to.

[image: tweaked plots]

What I want is for the 'high' argument of 'scale_fill_gradient2' to accept the corresponding items' value found in the 'high_value_color' variable of the data.

Comment: Start by removing `df$` from `aes()` calls.

Comment: Your intuition is right. You are passing 6 colors to the `high` argument of `scale_fill_gradient2`.

Comment: You're repeating yourself an awful lot with the subsetting, `df$item_group==plot_list[i]]`. Have the first line of your `for` loop be `sub_df = df[df$item_group==plot_list[i]], ]` and then use `sub_df` instead of subsetting every single data element every time you use it.

Comment: You probably want `high = unique(df$high_value_color[df$item_group == plot_list[i]]`.  If you've worked with `lapply` loops at all, I find `split` and `lapply` loops easier than `for` loops for creating a plot per group.

Comment: @aosmith Your response worked! I will certainly explore the lapply and split loops.

Answer (score 5):

Ok. The main problem was the passing of colors to `scale_fill_gradient2`. However, there is a lot more in your code that can be improved. Specifically, you want to only pass bare variable names to `aes`. I also don't see why you are constantly repeating your subsetting everywhere. You make it very likely for yourself to run into trouble.

Here is how I would probably tackle a problem like this:

First of all, we make a function that is a lot simpler: it only takes directly a data argument and simply makes the required plot with that data (no loop).

```
survey_items.graph <- function(dat) {
  ggplot(aes(x = item, y = respondent), data = dat) +
    geom_tile(aes(fill = score), colour = "black") + 
    scale_fill_gradient2(low = "azure1", 
                         high = dat$high_value_color[1], 
                         guide = "colorbar") +
    geom_text(aes(label = score), hjust = 0.5, angle = 90, size = 4) +
    ggtitle(dat$item_group[1]) +
    theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          panel.background = element_blank(),
          plot.title = element_text(size = 7, face="bold"),
          axis.text.y = element_text(size = 7, face ="bold"),
          axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1),
          axis.title = element_blank(),
          legend.position = "none")
}
```

We then `split` up your data in a list of data.frames, one per `item_group`:

```
split_data <- split(plot_df, plot_df$item_group)
```

Then we apply our function to each entry in the list, creating a list of plots:

```
plot_list <- lapply(split_data, survey_items.graph)
```

For convenience here, I use `grid.arrange` to quickly stitch both plots together:

```
library(gridExtra)
do.call(grid.arrange, plot_list)
```

I you want to save them you can use something like:

```
Map(function(x, i, ...) ggsave(paste0('plot', i, '.png'), x, ...), 
    plot_list, seq_along(plot_list), scale = 2)
```

[image]

Comment: Hey. The comment by @aosmith worked for my current approach. Nonetheless, I will explore your alternative for this and future projects.

Comment: @ealfons1 There are different approaches of course, but please at least fix you `aes` calls. Your way _will_ bite you in the behind sooner or later! Have a good weekend.

Comment: To be more explicit, using `$` inside `aes()` will work for simple ggplots, but it's a bad habit. It *will break* if there are facets or more complicated stat functions involved. There is no reason to ever do it.

Comment: Will remove the `$` from aes() calls.